# Stop azure databricks cluster after threshold time of job execution

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I need to know , how to stop a azure databricks cluster by doing configuration when it is running infinitely for executing a job.(without manual stopping)and as well as create an email alert for it, as the job running time exceeds its usual running time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the Jobs UI, Select your job, under Advanced, edit the Alerts and Timeout values.

[image: Databricks Job UI Advanced Alerts and Timeout]

This Databricks docs page may help you: https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html